# Is there a way I can have my computer go to sleep but be able to wake it up remotely?

Tags: sleep, wake-on-lan

I've heard of Wake-Up-On-LAN (well, I've seen it in the BIOS) but I've never been 100% how to work it. Would this do what I'm after, and if not - would anything else?

I'm using Windows 7, in case it matters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wake-On-LAN needs a specially-crafted packet sent from another machine on the LAN (hence the name) to work. If there isn't *some* other machine on the LAN that you can get to then it can't be done.

Comment: Can a router be that machine?

Comment: If you have some sort of shell access to the router, and if you can install the WoL client on it, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Magic Packet Utility from AMD.

http://www.amd.com/us-en/assets/content_type/utilities/magic_pkt.exe

EDIT: [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/networking/?p=2209) should explain a little...

Answer (score 0):

We use WOL in a large LAN. If you are thinking of doing WOL with a PC over the internet, I don't it would work. With the newer BIOS' it actually works, but beware since the drivers have to compatible or when your PC wakes up it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Wake-On-LAN can do exactly that. You need a computer that supports it, and to enable it in the bios as you mentioned. You need to consider where you want to send the message from: if it's from your LAN then you can use any old software (google it). I believe you can also wake it up from the internet, but there are some things to consider.

- you must have a static IP address for your internet connection
- your isp might filter out the packet (you can ask them not to!)
- if you have a router, it needs to be set up to forward the packet

If you do want to use the internet, I think there are some websites which will send the message for you.

HTH

Andy

Answer (score 0):

You could try [wake-on-modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-ring) if you're prepared to dedicate a telephone line to your computer (and hope you don't get wrong number / telemarketing calls).